# How to return relationship type with Neo4J's Cypher queries?

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I am trying to get the relationship type of a very simple Cypher query, like the following

```
MATCH (n)-[r]-(m) RETURN n, r, m;
```

Unfortunately this return an empty object for `r`. This is troublesome since I can't distinguish between the different types of relationships. I can monkey patch this by adding a property like `[r:KNOWS {type:'KNOWS'}]` but I am wondering if there isn't a direct way to get the relationship type.

I even followed the official [Neo4J tutorial](http://neo4j.com/docs/stable/query-return.html#return-return-all-elements) (as described below), demonstrating the problem.

**Graph Setup**:

```
create (_0 {`age`:55, `happy`:"Yes!", `name`:"A"})
create (_1 {`name`:"B"})
create _0-[:`KNOWS`]->_1
create _0-[:`BLOCKS`]->_1
```

**Query**:

```
MATCH p=(a { name: "A" })-[r]->(b)
RETURN *
```

**JSON RESPONSE BODY**:

```
{
    "results": [
        {
            "columns": [
                "a",
                "b",
                "p",
                "r"
            ],
            "data": [
                {
                    "row": [
                        {
                            "name": "A",
                            "age": 55,
                            "happy": "Yes!"
                        },
                        {
                            "name": "B"
                        },
                        [
                            {
                                "name": "A",
                                "age": 55,
                                "happy": "Yes!"
                            },
                            {},
                            {
                                "name": "B"
                            }
                        ],
                        {}
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "row": [
                        {
                            "name": "A",
                            "age": 55,
                            "happy": "Yes!"
                        },
                        {
                            "name": "B"
                        },
                        [
                            {
                                "name": "A",
                                "age": 55,
                                "happy": "Yes!"
                            },
                            {},
                            {
                                "name": "B"
                            }
                        ],
                        {}
                    ]
                }
            ]
        }
    ],
    "errors": []
}
```

As you can see, I get an empty object for `r`, which makes it impossible to distinguish between the relationships.

**NOTE**: I am running Neo4J v.2.2.2

Comment: It's just `TYPE(r)` where `r` is the relationship's identifier. Check it out here: http://neo4j.com/docs/stable/query-functions-scalar.html#functions-type

Comment: Great! That was easy. I am wondering why I haven't found that page.

Comment: It's not exactly featured. :) In the future, keep the Cypher refcard handy as it will show you things like that. http://neo4j.com/docs/stable/cypher-refcard/

Comment: I've been writing cypher for a few years now, and I always have the refcard and the cypher cheat sheet close by.

Comment: @FrobberOfBits Thanks, I guess you mean this PDF [assets.neo4j.org/download/Neo4j_CheatSheet_v3.pdf](http://assets.neo4j.org/download/Neo4j_CheatSheet_v3.pdf)

Comment: @NicoleWhite Thanks for the excellent tip!

Answer (score 54, accepted):

Use the `type()` function.

```
MATCH (n)-[r]-(m) RETURN type(r);
```

Answer (score 4):

Added distinct.

```
MATCH (n)-[r]-(m) RETURN distinct type(r);
```